# How to remove features from a Leaflet GeoJSON layer?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

In a Leaflet map, it is possible to add features to a [GeoJSON layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#geojson) using the `addData` method:

> `L.geoJSON:` Creates a GeoJSON layer. Optionally accepts an object in
>   GeoJSON format (you can alternatively add it later with addData
>   method)
>
> `addData(data)`: Adds a GeoJSON object to the layer.

Is it possible to *remove* all features from the GeoJSON layer, without destroying the layer and recreating it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that `GeoJSON` extends `FeatureGroup`, which extends `LayerGroup`, which has a method `clearLayers`().

This means that `jsonLayer.clearLayers()` can be used to remove the features from a GeoJSON layer.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layergroup

Comment: Hi, I see it is not a very new threat, but I can't solve a very similar problem - removing a geojson feature. Here is my code:   <br/>  > onClick: function()  {map.removeLayer(mygeojson)}     <br/>  Am I missing a point? I would appriciate if you could help  @Stephen Lead

Comment: @Gamze you should post this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)