# How to delete geohash rectangles from Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geohash

I have been inspired by [this code](https://codepen.io/jthomassie/pen/lvoGe) to create a geohash map for my Neo4j geohash graph on Leaflet: 
[image: geohash on leaflet]

Unlike the (lat/lon) markers, the geohash string is represented as a rectangle in the map.

For a static search, I return all the geohash nodes with an Ajax query in my Leaflet Map.

For a dynamic search I added a search  form, as you can see above the map, to query the Neo4j database by time ([timehash](https://github.com/abeusher/timehash) here for me).

The request to the database is working fine, and the new geohash rectangles are plotted in the map, however the previous geohash rectangles remains.

How do I delete the previous geohash rectangle from the map?

Comment: Solved :I found the Solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218935/how-to-remove-features-from-a-leaflet-geojson-layer)