# Leaflet - remove data from layer?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, large-datasets

I have a quite complex webapp with a lot of data on a map. Except the basemap, the data of each layers are coming from AJAX queries, witch's responses are formatted as GeoJSON object -- up to this works fine. (Each of this responses -- so each GeoJSON object -- can be more than 1 Mb.)

With checkboxes I'd like to show or hide the datasets.

I prepare each layer in this way: `var layer_1 = L.geoJSON(null, { style: style_1, pane: "pane_1" }).addTo(myMap);`.

I can add data: `layer_1.addData(data_1.responseJSON);`.

If I'd like to hide this dataset, is it possible somehow to remove only this dataset from `layer_1` (as "opposite" of `addData()`), or the only way is to `myMap.removeLayer(layer_1);`, and then create the layer again?

Comment: One way of achieving what you want would be `LayerGroup`, see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layergroup

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that could be averted by instantiating several `L.GeoJSON` instances, one per dataset.

Answer (score 3):

On hand of these answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218948/171957 it's possible to empty the dataset with `jsonLayer.clearLayers()`.

Comment: This is not correct answer to the question. Method `.clearLayers()` clears all the features from the layer, but question is how to hide/remove only particular  subset of layers.